# Show Swagger validation information

Tags: rest, api, swagger

Swagger UI does not show request parameter's validation information.
I want to show parameter's min value, max value, format, pattern(regex). Does anyone know the way how I express the parameter's validation information on Swagger UI?

Comment: How did you install Swagger UI? Do you use the vanilla version downloaded from the [repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) (or installed via npm), or do you use Swagger UI bundled with some framework/library (e.g. Swashbuckle or Springfox)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using openapi 3.0.0 I got a UI with validation information like that displayed in http://editor.swagger.io/. Conversion from openapi 2 to openapi 3 could be done at the following URL. https://mermade.org.uk/openapi-converter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Swagger UI 3.x (the latest version), add `showCommonExtensions: true` to the Swagger UI initialization code in your `index.html` file:

```js
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
  url: "https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  showCommonExtensions: true,    // <-----
  ...
```

[Learn more about Swagger UI configuration parameters.](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md)